# iOS KVO superclass

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying through KVO reach a superclass and then a object which has a property. It looks likes this

```
SuperCell(UITableViewCell) - Person * - name(NSString*)

/\

Cell(SuperCell)
```

It keeps crashing when I do this:

```
[cell valueForKey:@"person.name"];
```

But when I do this it works:

```
[[cell valueForKey:@"person"] valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Is it possible to do the first style? Or do I need to split it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `valueForKeyPath:` instead.

```
[cell valueForKeyPath:@"person.name"];
```